# Change active step color of stepper using reactjs and material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hi guys i m using reactjs and material ui for project i want to change the color of active tab in stepper. Is there is any props or other thing we can use to solve this problem.I am using old version of reactjs and material ui 15 for reactjs and 0.16 for material

```
return (
      <div style={{width: '100%', maxWidth: 700, margin: 'auto'}}>
        <Stepper seconda activeStep={stepIndex}>
          <Step>
            <StepLabel>Select campaign settings</StepLabel>
          </Step>
          <Step>
            <StepLabel>Create an ad group</StepLabel>
          </Step>
          <Step>
            <StepLabel>Create an ad</StepLabel>
          </Step>
        </Stepper>
        <div style={contentStyle}>
          {finished ? (
            <p>
              <a
                href="#"
                onClick={(event) => {
                  event.preventDefault();
                  this.setState({stepIndex: 0, finished: false});
                }}
              >
                Click here
              </a> to reset the example.
            </p>
          ) : (
            <div>
              <p>{this.getStepContent(stepIndex)}</p>
              <div style={{marginTop: 12}}>
                <FlatButton
                  label="Back"
                  disabled={stepIndex === 0}
                  onClick={this.handlePrev}
                  style={{marginRight: 12}}
                />
                <RaisedButton
                  label={stepIndex === 2 ? 'Finish' : 'Next'}
                  primary={true}
                  onClick={this.handleNext}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have two options:

You could customize the theme:

[theme customization](http://www.material-ui.com/#/customization/themes)

But the easiest way would be using the inkBarStyle property.
You can see it in the docs..
Example:

```
<Tabs inkBarStyle={{background: 'blue'}}>...
```